# Running a function on the main thread from a boost thread and passing parameters to that function

Tags: boost, boost-asio, boost-thread, boost-bind

I have some code running in a boost thread that modifies stuff handled by the main thread which is not working and it makes sense.

On android i would have the `Handler` which is a message queue that would execute my code on the main thread and i can pass whatever parameters i want to this handler.

I want to do the same with boost

so on my main thread i do the following:

```
boost::thread workerThread(boost::bind(&SomeClass::pollService, this));
```

My pollService method:

```
SomeClass::pollService()
{
     //get some stuff from a web service
     //parse the json response
     //NEEDED part: call a function to be executed on the main thread and hand it some functions
}
```

P.S. I have looked at many `io_service.post` examples and i still have no clue how to do it, and also i read an answer that said to use `asio` `strand` but i am also unable to understand it.

Can some one please dumb it down for me ?
Please don't write something so abstract that i won't understand, I am not experienced in this.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `io_service::post()` is a convenient facility to post a functor from one thread to another, but the destination thread should execute `io_service::run()`, which is blocking function (it's kind of `io_service` "message loop"). So, assuming your main thread looks like this:

```
int main()
{
  // do some preparations, launch other threads...
  // ...
  io_service io;
  io.run();
}
```

...and assuming you've got an access to `io` object from `pollService` running in another thread, you can do the following:

```
SomeClass::pollService()
{
  // do something...
  // ...
  io.post([=] { doStuffThatShoudRunInMainThread(); });
}
```

If your compiler doesn't support c++11 lambdas, use `bind` -- but note that `post` expects nullary functor, i.e. a function-object that doesn't accept parameters.

Comment: So how do I pass on parameters to my function ?

Comment: Just a note, i already fixed my problem by making an std:queue and putting stuff in it and while(!queue.empty()) i do stuff in the gui thread which already loops every tick, and it is working fine, i need to know just to know how to do it right in the future

Comment: @Shereef if you use lambda syntax - pass the params directly to `doStuffThatShoudRunInMainThread()`, otherwise bind the parameters when creating the functor: `bind(&doStuffThatShoudRunInMainThread, arg1, arg2, arg3)`. Of course, if it's a member function you should bind it with `this` or better with `shared_from_this`.

Comment: Can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/13785640/435706 , Thank you

Comment: void funtionToCreateThread() { //code to update ui //create thread //thread join}  here thread join code blocks update ui calls at the begining,  how to fix this ? Since ioserver run is also a blocking call i feel that first comment code wont work. can you suggest how to get by this ?

Comment: @Satyam Raikar I think it's worth creating a new question.