# boost thread pool bind errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm using `boost::asio` and `boost::filesystem` to perform some simple asynchronous filesystem operations.
The following code snippet is supposed to spawn a new thread for every directory it finds in the first level that recurses such directory, and so on, as long as there are threads to use from the thread pool.

It seems that the compiler does not recognize that I am passing the `boost::asio::io_service` by reference, and complains:

`main.cpp:51:51: Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'boost::asio::io_service'`

I tried `#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_MOVE` so it would think it is allowed to move the `boost::asio::io_service` even though it is really being passed by `const &`, but to no avail.

Includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
// Threadpool
#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_MOVE
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
// Filesystem
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
    boost::thread_group threadpool;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(ioservice);
    unsigned int threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
        threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,
                                 &ioservice));


    ioservice.post(boost::bind(parallel_found_file,
                               ioservice, // Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'boost::asio::io_service'
                               APPS_DIR,
                               FILE_NAME));
    threadpool.join_all();
    ioservice.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

Function:

```
static bool parallel_found_file(boost::asio::io_service & ioservice,
                                 const boost::filesystem::path & dir_path,
                                 const std::string & file_name)
{
    if(!exists(dir_path))
        return true;

    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_itr;
    for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr(dir_path);
        itr != end_itr;
        ++itr )
    {
        if(is_directory(itr->status()))
        {
            ioservice.post(boost::bind(parallel_found_file,
                                       ioservice, // Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'boost::asio::io_service'
                                       itr->path(),
                                       file_name));
        }
        else
        {
            if(itr->path().filename().string().find(file_name)
               != std::string::npos)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit:

```
ioservice.post(boost::bind(parallel_remove_file,
                           boost::ref(ioservice),
                           boost::ref(APPS_DIR),
                           boost::ref(FILE_NAME)));
```

`io_service.hpp:102:3: Static_assert failed "CompletionHandler type requirements not met"`

[`boost::asio::io_service::post` says](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html):
The function signature of the handler must be:
`void handler();`

Does this mean there's no way for me to pass or return values from the function? Since the required signature of the handler takes no parameters and has no return?

This works now, but I would really like to know why I can't pass parameters or a return value, only captured variables, or variables from outside the scope :/

```
auto ioref = std::ref(ioservice);
ioservice.post([ioref]()
               -> void
               { parallel_remove_file(ioref, APPS_DIR, FILE_NAME); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::bind`, like `std::bind`, **takes its template parameters by value**.

It doesn't matter that the parameters will eventually be bound to a function taking references.  The copy has already been attempted.

You can fix this by wrapping the parameter with [`boost::ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/ref.html).  Or [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).  Either one will create an object that behaves like a reference to the original wrapped object, even when copied.

```
result = ioservice.post(boost::bind(parallel_found_file,
                                    boost::ref(ioservice),
                                    itr->path(),
                                    file_name));
```

It will then be your responsibility to ensure that `ioservice` lives as long as the bound function.

Also, it is not possible to pass parameters to `io_service::post` rather, you must capture variables through a lambda capture list or bind. [See this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680770/running-a-function-on-the-main-thread-from-a-boost-thread-and-passing-parameters)

Comment: Interesting, that was the problem. So `boost::ref()` passes a copy of a reference to the variable?

Also, bind continues to give me headaches:

`main.cpp:68:10: Variable has incomplete type 'void'`

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera if you can use `auto`, you're using C++11 or later.  I'd recommend using a lambda here instead of `boost::bind` as people seem to find lambdas much less confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I honestly don't even know what `boost::bind` or `std::bind` are, i'm new to c++ and going off examples. I tried using a lambda and have run into a caveat. See the edit.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera This [blog](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/bind-illustrated.html) may help provide some insight into `bind()`.

Comment: @TannerSansbury Especially this sentence "bind can be used to adapt a user-supplied function expecting one argument into a function object that takes zero arguments." Every other resource overcomplicates what a bind means and/or what it does to the point it is incomprehensible. xD