# lambda to curl callback function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to pass a lambda to the [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html).

The function expects a static function, however, I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525370/how-to-pass-a-non-static-member-function-as-a-unique-ptr-deleter) that a lambda would be implicitly converted, and I could call the member function from the lambda.

```
auto callback = [](char * ptr_data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string * writerData)
->size_t
{
    if(writerData == NULL)
        return 0;
    size_t data_size = size * nmemb;
    writerData->append(ptr_data, data_size);
    return (int)data_size;
};

CURLcode code = curl_easy_setopt(conn, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
```

This actually compiles, but curl segfaults: `Segmentation fault: 11`

I pasted the full example [here](http://pastebin.com/0EKx9fhH).

Comment: Looking at your snippet, don't you want: `code = curl_easy_setopt(conn, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);` to be called before you call `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`? Otherwise the pointer to pass to the callback is not set.

Comment: @JesseGood, The order doesn't matter as long as I set them before calling `curl_easy_perform`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magic is, add the leading "+" at the non-captured lambda expression, which will trigger conversion to plain C function pointer.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,
  /* NOTE: Leader '+' trigger conversion from non-captured Lambda Object to plain C pointer */
  +[](void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) -> size_t {
    // invoke the member function via userp
    return size * nmemb;
  });
```

My understanding is, `curl_easy_setopt` wants a `void*`, not an explicit function type, so the compiler just gives the address of lambda object; if we do a function pointer operation on lambda object, the compiler will return the function pointer from lambda object.

Answer (score 3):

A lambda closure is convertible to a function pointer **only** if the lambda has no captures.

Your lambda is capturing `[this]` so it cannot be converted.

*Edit: this was an answer to the original revision of the question.*

Comment: While not curl specific, [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657011) other [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744) are similar.

Comment: see my edit, I was aware of this, and was testing different configurations, because curl still segfaults in all cases.